# How to use "ON UPDATE CASCADE" Correctly in MariaDB 10.1.37 / Ver 15.1?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am experiencing trouble getting ON UPDATE CASCADE to work with a CONSTRAINT.  If I use UPDATE to change the value of **customerName** in the **customer** table, it will not change the **customerName** value in the **city** table.  No error message shows up.

The version of the MariaDB:

```
Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB
```

My **city** table when using *SHOW CREATE TABLE city*:

```
city  | CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `cityId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countryId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdateBy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cityId`),
  KEY `customerNameChange01` (`customerName`),
  CONSTRAINT `customerNameChange01` FOREIGN KEY (`customerName`) 
      REFERENCES `customer` (`customerName`)
      ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

My **customer** table *SHOW CREATE TABLE customer*:

```
customer | CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `customerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `addressId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createDate` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdBy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastUpdateBy` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerId`),
  KEY `CustomerName` (`customerName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

These are the commands I used to create the index and CONSTRAINT:

```
CREATE INDEX CustomerName ON customer (customerName);

ALTER TABLE city
  ADD CONSTRAINT customerNameChange01
  FOREIGN KEY (customerName)
  REFERENCES customer (customerName)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

In the customer table, the **CustomerName** key references an index.  Otherwise, I would not have been able to put in the CONSTRAINT in the **city** table.

*Update:*  The code works fine in DB Fiddle for MariaDB 10.2 and personal testing confirms that the example code from there works in my own database as well.

Thank you for spending your time.

Comment: Why not reference the customer id instead of the customer name ?

Comment: Your code works just fine in [this MariaDB 10.2 DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=232f7f88ff5a9d3c89ceeea344824737) : the child table is getting updated. I don't know about a MariaDB 10.1 DB fiddle available. I tested in MySQL 5.5 and it worked too.

Comment: @GMB  A lot of bad logic will be going into the database design.  I do not have the advantage of time to re-write the original software.

Comment: @GMB  Okay, thank you.  I will double check my results.

Comment: I guess that means I should next try upgrading the database to at least MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: I cannot test it on 10.1, does not necessarily means it does not work. Maybe you can you take the code from the fiddle and execute it exactly as it is on your system, to see what happens ?

Comment: @GMB  Good idea.

Comment: @GMB  Well, it did work.  Maybe it is the connector for the Java software client I am using or me being logged in as root during the testing.

Comment: It is an improper database design to have CustomerName redundantly in two places; you have a CustomerId as a surrogate for the Name.  If you don't understand what "constraints" will and won't do, don't use them; they are optional.